# Distributing via TestFlight when app already published on Apple Store

Tags: ios, itunes, testflight

One of the apps I've already published on Apple Store, and can I share the same via TestFlight?

When I check on iTunes Connect, particular version status says Invalid Binary. But there is no reasons from the Apple either. So is this because already published, or some other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Upload a new build with an updated number and you can share it via testflight

Comment: Yes, that's one option I've. Still I'm wonder why it says "Invalid Binary", just want to make sure users are not impacted. After the release I've renewed distribution certificate, that might be the cause?